# Proving that cuboid of maximum volume in a sphere is a cube.

Tags: derivatives, volume, maxima-minima, applications, spheres

I was preparing for my maths test . And preparing application of derivative (theory based question ) there I saw a problem of proving rectangle of maximum area in a circle is square . So there were two variables and I was able to find one in terms of other by applying Pythagoras since diagonal of rectangle is diameter of circle.
But soon I thought of a problem that similarly a cuboid of maximum volume in a sphere would be a cube .
But when I went of proving there were three different variables for length ,breadth and height  and i m not able to convert two of them in one variable. So it is becoming a constant problem for me . So please guide how should I move further so that I can change three variables into one .
I hope you guys understood my problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the rectangular prism's length, depth and height a function of x. This is doable because the prism fits into a sphere. Consider a view looking onto one face of the prism with the origin of a coordinate grid at the center of the circumscribing sphere. The length is $2x$, and the height and depth are both $2\sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$, where $r$ is the radius of the sphere.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is awesome but I m unable to visualize it

Comment: How you found height and depth???

Comment: @Ritik See added sketch to my edited answer.

Comment: How you found Maxima because I m finding Maxima it is coming as x=1/root3

Comment: @Ritik That' because when angle $\theta$ is greater than $45$ deg the depth becomes $2x$ and not $2\sqrt(1-x^2)$. It's tricky because the volume doesn't increase further after r passes through $45$ deg. If you used $dV/dx = 0$ to obtain $V$max, that will give you an incorrect answer because at $x = \sqrt(1/3)$ the depth is $2x$ and not $2\sqrt(1-x^2)$. You probably calculate $V$max as $3.0972$ which isn't correct. $V$max is when $\theta = 45$ deg.

Comment: Thanks sir I got it!